# surface area of a sphere above a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, analytic-geometry

I need to find the surface area of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ above the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but I'm not sure how. I know that the surface area of a surface can be calculated with the equation $A=\int{\int_D{\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}}}dA$, but I'm not sure how to take into account the constraint that it must lie above the cone. How is this done?

Comment: If you want to do it the way you set out, you find the intersection of the cone and the sphere, and you get a circle satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ and $z = $ some constant which you may not need.  So you need to integrate your integrand over a disc.  Use polar coordinates.  I am pretty sure you get an integral that is not that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is setup for spherical coordinates, so I would recommend you don't use the surface area formula you've written in terms of Cartesian coordinates.

Since $r=2$ is fixed, the infinitesimal area element in spherical coordinates is $dA=4\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.  The spherical cap is bounded by $0<\theta<\pi/4$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$.  So try to evaluate the integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}4\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: It's coming out negative, even though this is a surface integral. Why is that?

Comment: The answer should be $8\pi(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ which is not negative.  Try checking your calculations again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use spherical coordinates. $dA = r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ with $0<\theta<\pi$. The surface area becomes $\iint_D dA$.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it in the $xz$ plane, the sphere becomes a circle of radius $2$ and the cone becomes the pair of lines $z=x$ and $z=-x$.  These intersect at $x=z=\sqrt 2$ and at $x=-\sqrt 2, z=\sqrt 2$.  So you are looking for the part of the sphere above $z=\sqrt 2$.  In spherical coordinates, that is $0 \le \theta \le \frac \pi 4$