# Surface area of a sphere above a cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The surface area of S can be calculated by $\iint_R \sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + 1} dydx.$

In reference to this question
[surface area of a sphere above a cylinder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376740/surface-area-of-a-sphere-above-a-cylinder),  I first computed the square root in terms of cartesian coordinates before converting it into spherical coordinates:
$$x = 2 \cos\theta\sin\varphi 
\\ y = 2 \sin\theta\sin\varphi
$$ where $0 \le \theta\le2\pi$ and $0 \le \varphi \le\pi/4 $

and then multiplying it by the absolute value of the Jacobian, $r^2\sin\varphi $.

However this did not give me $4\sin(\varphi)$.

Why does this method work for polar coordinates but not for spherical coordinates?

My working out:
$$ z = \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2} 
\\ f_x = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}}
\\ f_y = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}}
\\\sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + 1} = \sqrt{(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}})^2 + 
(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}})^2 + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{4}{4 - x^2 - y^2}}
$$

Substituting the spherical coordinates into the above equation:
$$ \sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 - \sin^2(\varphi)}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(\varphi)}} = \frac{1}{\cos\varphi}
$$

Hence, we get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\cos\varphi}*4\sin\varphi d\varphi d\theta$$

Comment: Give more details on your work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just posted my working out.

Comment: Thank you. What is wrong with this ?

Comment: In the link I posted, the accepted answer has a different integral. I am not sure whether it's actually wrong or I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: In spherical coordinates, the element of area already takes into account the curvature of the surface, so that the factor $\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}$ mustn't be there. If you keep it, you are actually working with cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.